# gracefully stop execution a resque job without fail status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, resque

Im trying to get a resque job stopped certain condition,
but without the job getting an failed status in the resque web interface.

Tried exit() and return which both throw an failed status for the job.

How to gracefully stop code execution in a resque job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop execution without reporting a failed status:

`raise Resque::Job::DontPerform`

in a before_perform hook.

This isn't well documented, but you can find a reference in [the code](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/job.rb#L20).

*Update*: Resque [hooks documentation](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/docs/HOOKS.md)

Comment: resque moved from defunkt/resque to [resque/resque](http://github.com/resque/resque)

Comment: DO we have something like this in Sidekiq?

Comment: `break` results in a LocalJumpError, which then goes into the failed queue.. anyone actually have a solution to this? I know.. old thread.